# How to execute an arbitrary simple command over ssh without knowing the login shell of the remote user?

Tags: ssh, quoting, portability

`ssh` has an annoying feature in that when you run:

```bash
ssh user@host cmd and "here's" "one arg"
```

Instead of running that `cmd` with its arguments on `host`, it concatenates that `cmd` and arguments with spaces and runs a shell on `host` to interpret the resulting string (I guess that's why its called `ssh` and not `sexec`).

Worse, you don't know what shell is going to be used to interpret that string as that's the login shell of `user` which is not even guaranteed to be Bourne like as there are still people using `tcsh` as their login shell and `fish` is on the rise.

Is there a way around that?

Suppose I have a command as a list of arguments stored in a `bash` array, each of which may contain any sequence of non-null bytes,
is there any way to have it executed on `host` as `user` in a consistent way regardless of the login shell of that `user` on `host` (which we'll assume is one of the major Unix shell families: Bourne, csh, rc/es, fish)?

Another reasonable assumption that I should be able to make is that there be a `sh` command on `host` available in `$PATH` that is Bourne-compatible.

Example:

```bash
cmd=(
  'printf'
  '<%s>\n'
  'arg with $and spaces'
  '' # empty
  $'even\n* * *\nnewlines'
  "and 'single quotes'"
  '!!'
)
```

I can run it locally with `ksh`/`zsh`/`bash`/`yash` as:

```shell
$ "${cmd[@]}"
<arg with $and spaces>
<>
<even
* * *
newlines>
<and 'single quotes'>
<!!>
```

or

```bash
env "${cmd[@]}"
```

or

```bash
xterm -hold -e "${cmd[@]}"
...
```

How would I run it on `host` as `user` over `ssh`?

```bash
ssh user@host "${cmd[@]}"
```

obviously won't work.

```bash
ssh user@host "$(printf ' %q' exec "${cmd[@]}")"
```

would only work if the login shell of the remote user was the same as the local shell (or understands quoting in the same way as `printf %q` in the local shell produces it) and runs in the same locale.

Comment: If the `cmd` argument was `/bin/sh -c` we would end up with a posix shell in 99% of all cases, wouldn't we? Of course escaping special characters is a bit more painful this way, but would it solve the initial problem?

Comment: @Bananguin, no if you run `ssh host sh -c 'some cmd'`, same as `ssh host 'sh -c some cmd'`, that has the login shell of the remote user interpret that `sh -c some cmd` command line. We need to write the command in the correct syntax for that shell (and we don't know which it is) so that `sh` be called over there with `-c` and `some cmd` arguments.

Comment: I think you would have to do `ssh host sh -c "'some cmd'"` . But then you're stuck with the possibility that the remote side's shell will interpolate `some cmd` in a way you don't want. Is that the problem? Then what about simply running `echo command-string | ssh /bin/sh`?

Comment: @Otheus, yes, the `sh -c 'some cmd'` and `some cmd` command lines happen to be interpreted the same in all those shells. Now what if I want to run the `echo \'` Bourne command line on the remote host? `echo command-string | ssh ... /bin/sh` is one solution I gave in my answer, but that means you can't feed data to the stdin of that remote command.

Comment: Sounds like a more long-lasting solution would be an rexec plugin for ssh, ala the ftp plugin.

Comment: I'm not sure but it looks like the space in `' %q'` is superfluous.

Comment: @myrdd, no it's not, you need either space or tab to separate arguments in a shell command line. If `cmd` is `cmd=(echo "foo bar")`, the shell command line passed to `ssh` should be something like ` 'echo' 'foo bar'`. The *first* space (the one before `echo`) is superflous, but doen't harm. The other one (the ones before `'foo bar'`) is needed. With `'%q'`, we'd pass a `'echo''foo bar'` command line.

Comment: okay, so with `cmd=(echo "foo bar")`, `'%q'` would translate to ``'echo''foo bar'`` (incorrect), but ``' %q'`` translates to `` 'echo' 'foo bar'``. Thanks for clarification! (_Edit:_ weird markdown syntax bug…)

Comment: @myrdd, probably my bad, I must have one too many or too few backticks in my previous comment.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas primarily it's a bug, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125764/388007 — the character sequence `<backtick><space>` in your comment was ignored, and the next occurrence of a backtick was followed by a dot (`<backtick><dot>`). Since a dot is not a space (obviously…; refer to the Meta.SE question), and backtick parsing seems to be greedy, `<backtick><dot>` is the _beginning_ of a code. Ugly bug. I'll comment this tho the Meta.SE question.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas FYI, I found a workaround to this SE bug, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319440/388007. If you use it to repost [your above comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205567/how-to-execute-an-arbitrary-simple-command-over-ssh-without-knowing-the-login-sh?noredirect=1#comment891090_205567), we could remove the other comments, keeping the comments section clean.. well, if you care ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think any implementation of `ssh` has a native way to pass a command from client to server without involving a shell.

Now, things can get easier if you can tell the remote shell to only run a specific interpreter (like `sh`, for which we know the expected syntax) and give the code to execute by another mean.

That other mean can be for instance *standard input* or an *environment variable*.

When neither can be used, I propose a hacky third solution below.

#### Using stdin

If you don't need to feed any data to the remote command, that's the easiest solution.

If you know the remote host has an `xargs` command that supports the `-0` option and the command is not too large, you can do:

```bash
printf '%s\0' "${cmd[@]}" | ssh user@host 'xargs -0 env --'
```

That `xargs -0 env --` command line is interpreted the same with all those shell families. `xargs` reads the null-delimited list of arguments on stdin and passes those as arguments to `env`. That assumes the first argument (the command name) does not contain `=` characters.

Or you can use `sh` on the remote host after having quoted each element using `sh` quoting syntax.

```bash
shquote() {
  LC_ALL=C awk -v q=\' '
    BEGIN{
      for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) {
        gsub(q, q "\\" q q, ARGV[i])
        printf "%s ", q ARGV[i] q
      }
      print ""
    }' "$@"
}
shquote "${cmd[@]}" | ssh user@host sh
```

Or just:

```bash
print -r -- ${(qq)cmd} | ssh user@host sh
```

If using zsh as the local shell.

#### Using environment variables

Now, if you do need to feed some data from the client to the remote command's stdin, the above solution won't work.

Some `ssh` server deployments however allow passing of arbitrary environment variables from the client to the server. For instance, many openssh deployments on Debian based systems allow passing variables whose name starts with `LC_`.

In those cases you could have a `LC_CODE` variable for instance containing the *shquoted* `sh` code as above and run `sh -c 'eval "$LC_CODE"'` on the remote host after having told your client to pass that variable (again, that's a command-line that's interpreted the same in every shell):

```bash
LC_CODE=$(shquote "${cmd[@]}") ssh -o SendEnv=LC_CODE user@host '
  sh -c '\''eval "$LC_CODE"'\'
```

Or:

```bash
LC_CODE=${(qqj[ ])cmd} ssh -o SendEnv=LC_CODE user@host '
  sh -c '\''eval "$LC_CODE"'\'
```

in `zsh`.

#### Building a command line compatible to all shell families

If none of the options above are acceptable (because you need stdin and sshd doesn't accept any variable, or because you need a generic solution), then you'll have to prepare a command line for the remote host that is compatible with all supported shells.

That is particularly tricky because all those shells (Bourne, csh, rc, es, fish) have their own different syntax, and in particular different quoting mechanisms and some of them have limitations that are hard to work around.

Here is a solution I came up with, I describe it further down:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
my $arg, @ssh, $preamble =
q{printf '%.0s' "'\";set x=\! b=\\\\;setenv n "\
";set q=\';printf %.0s "\""'"';q='''';n=``()echo;x=!;b='\'
printf '%.0s' '\'';set b \\\\;set x !;set -x n \n;set q \'
printf '%.0s' '\'' #'"\"'";export n;x=!;b=\\\\;IFS=.;set `echo;echo \.`;n=$1 IFS= q=\'
};

@ssh = ('ssh');
while ($arg = shift @ARGV and $arg ne '--') {
  push @ssh, $arg;
}

if (@ARGV) {
  for (@ARGV) {
    s/'/'\$q\$b\$q\$q'/g;
    s/\n/'\$q'\$n'\$q'/g;
    s/!/'\$x'/g;
    s/\\/'\$b'/g;
    $_ = "\$q'$_'\$q";
  }
  push @ssh, "${preamble}exec sh -c 'IFS=;exec '" . join "' '", @ARGV;
}

exec @ssh;
```

That's a `perl` wrapper script around `ssh`. I call it `sexec`. You call it like:

```bash
sexec [ssh-options] user@host -- cmd and its args
```

so in your example:

```bash
sexec user@host -- "${cmd[@]}"
```

And the wrapper turns `cmd and its args` into a command line that all shells end up interpreting as calling `cmd` with its args (regarless of their content).

Limitations:

- The preamble and the way the command is quoted means the remote command line ends up being significantly larger which means the limit on the maximum size of a command line will be reached sooner.
- I've only tested it with: Bourne shell (from heirloom toolchest), dash, bash, zsh, mksh, lksh, yash, ksh93, rc, es, akanga, csh, tcsh, fish as found on a recent Debian system and /bin/sh, /usr/bin/ksh, /bin/csh and /usr/xpg4/bin/sh on Solaris 10.
- If `yash` is the remote login shell, you can't pass a command whose arguments contain invalid characters, but that's a limitation in `yash` that you can't work around anyway.
- Some shells like csh or bash read some startup files when invoked over ssh. We assume those don't change the behaviour dramatically so that the preamble still works.
- beside `sh`, it also assumes the remote system has the `printf` command.

To understand how it works, you need to know how quoting works in the different shells:

- Bourne: `'...'` are strong quotes with *no* special character in it. `"..."` are weak quotes where `"` can be escaped with backslash.
- `csh`. Same as Bourne except that `"` cannot be escaped inside `"..."`. Also a newline character has to be entered prefixed with a backslash. And `!` causes problems even inside single quotes.
- `rc`. The only quotes  are `'...'` (strong). A single quote within single quotes is entered as `''` (like `'...''...'`). Double quotes or backslashes are not special.
- `es`. Same as rc except that outside quotes, backslash can escape a single quote.
- `fish`: same as Bourne except that backslash escapes `'` inside `'...'`.

With all those contraints, it's easy to see that one cannot reliably quote command line arguments so that it works with all shells.

Using single quotes as in:

```bash
'foo' 'bar'
```

works in all but:

```bash
'echo' 'It'\''s'
```

would not work in `rc`.

```bash
'echo' 'foo
bar'
```

would not work in `csh`.

```bash
'echo' 'foo\'
```

would not work in `fish`.

However we should be able to work around most of those problems if we manage to store those problematic characters in variables, like backslash in `$b`, single quote in `$q`, newline in `$n` (and `!` in `$x` for csh history expansion) in a shell independant way.

```bash
'echo' 'It'$q's'
'echo' 'foo'$b
```

would work in all shells. That would still not work for newline for `csh` though. If `$n` contains newline, in `csh`, you have to write it as `$n:q` for it to expand to a newline and that won't work for other shells. So, what we end-up doing instead here is calling `sh` and have `sh` expand those `$n`. That also means having to do two levels of quoting, one for the remote login shell, and one for `sh`.

The `$preamble` in that code is the trickiest part. It makes use of the various different quoting rules in all shells to have some sections of the code interpreted by only one of the shells (while it's commented out for the others) each of which just defining those `$b`, `$q`, `$n`, `$x` variables for their respective shell.

Here's the shell code that would be interpreted by the login shell of the remote user on `host` for your example:

```bash
printf '%.0s' "'\";set x=\! b=\\;setenv n "\
";set q=\';printf %.0s "\""'"';q='''';n=``()echo;x=!;b='\'
printf '%.0s' '\'';set b \\;set x !;set -x n \n;set q \'
printf '%.0s' '\'' #'"\"'";export n;x=!;b=\\;IFS=.;set `echo;echo \.`;n=$1 IFS= q=\'
exec sh -c 'IFS=;exec '$q'printf'$q' '$q'<%s>'$b'n'$q' '$q'arg with $and spaces'$q' '$q''$q' '$q'even'$q'$n'$q'* * *'$q'$n'$q'newlines'$q' '$q'and '$q$b$q$q'single quotes'$q$b$q$q''$q' '$q''$x''$x''$q
```

That code ends up running the same command when interpreted by any of the supported shells.

Comment: The SSH protocol ([RFC 4254 §6.5](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4254.txt)) defines a remote command as a string. It's up to the server to decide how to interpret that string. On Unix systems, the normal interpretation is to pass the string to the user's login shell. For a restricted account, that could be something like rssh or rush that doesn't accept arbitrary commands. There could even be a forced command on the account or on the key that causes the command string sent by the client to be ignored.

Comment: @Gilles, thanks for the RFC reference. Yes, the assumption for this Q&A is that the login shell of the remote user is usable (as in I can run that remote command I want to run) and one of the main shell families on POSIX systems. I'm not interested in restricted shells or non-shells or force commands or anything that won't allow me run that remote command anyway.

Comment: An useful reference about the main differences in syntax between some common shells can be found at [Hyperpolyglot](http://hyperpolyglot.org/unix-shells).

Comment: An environment variable which is always passed when a pseudo-terminal is required is `TERM`. So a possible variant of the envvar kludge may be `TERM=remote_commands... ssh -qt host 'sh -c '\''eval "$TERM"'\'`

Answer (score 0):

#### tl;dr

```bsh
ssh USER@HOST -p PORT $(printf "%q" "cmd") $(printf "%q" "arg1") \
    $(printf "%q" "arg2")
```

For a more elaborate solution, read the comments and inspect [the other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205569/29867).

#### description

Well, my solution won't work with non-`bash` shells. But assuming it's `bash` on the other end, things get simpler. My idea is to reuse `printf "%q"` for escaping. Also generally, it's more readable to have a script on the other end, that accepts arguments. But if the command is short, it's probably okay to inline it. Here are some example functions to use in scripts:

`local.sh`:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

ssh_run() {
    local user_host_port=($(echo "$1" | tr '@:' ' '))
    local user=${user_host_port[0]}
    local host=${user_host_port[1]}
    local port=${user_host_port[2]-22}
    shift 1
    local cmd=("$@")
    local a qcmd=()
    for a in ${cmd[@]+"${cmd[@]}"}; do
        qcmd+=("$(printf "%q" "$a")")
    done
    ssh "$user"@"$host" -p "$port" ${qcmd[@]+"${qcmd[@]}"}
}

ssh_cmd() {
    local user_host_port=$1
    local cmd=$2
    shift 2
    local args=("$@")
    ssh_run "$user_host_port" bash -lc "$cmd" - ${args[@]+"${args[@]}"}
}

ssh_run USER@HOST ./remote.sh "1  '  \"  2" '3  '\''  "  4'
ssh_cmd USER@HOST:22 "for a; do echo \"'\$a'\"; done" "1  '  \"  2" '3  '\''  "  4'
ssh_cmd USER@HOST:22 'for a; do echo "$a"; done' '1  "2' "3'  4"
```

`remote.sh`:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
for a; do
    echo "'$a'"
done
```

The output:

```
'1  '  "  2'
'3  '  "  4'
'1  '  "  2'
'3  '  "  4'
1  "2
3'  4
```

Alternatively, you can do `printf`'s job yourself, if you know what you're doing:

```bsh
ssh USER@HOST ./1.sh '"1  '\''  \"  2"' '"3  '\''  \"  4"'
```

Comment: That assumes the login shell of the remote user is bash (as bash's printf %q quotes in a bash fashion) and that `bash` be available on the remote machine. There are also a few problems with missing quotes which would cause problems with whitespace and wildcards.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Indeed, my solution is probably targeting only `bash` shells. But hopefully people will find it of use. I tried to address the other issues though. Feel free to tell me if there's anything I'm missing other than the `bash` thing.

Comment: Note that it still doesn't work with the sample command in the question (`ssh_run user@host "${cmd[@]}"`). You still have some missing quotes.

Comment: That's better. Note that the output of bash's `printf %q` is not safe to use in a different locale (and is also quite buggy; for instance in locales using the BIG5 charset, it (4.3.48) quotes `ε` as `α\``!). For that, best is to quote everything and with single quotes only like with the `shquote()` in my answer.