# How to interpret ' character in a string passed through SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, escape-characters, special-characters

New to BASH and Linux and need some quick help. I have written a quick bash script that asks the user for a username and password from the command line and passes that info to a remote server later via SSH. Problem is, one user has a ' character in the password and the value is causing EOF errors when using SSH. The following is my code to capture the username and password

```
echo "Please type in username:"
read username
read -s -p "Enter Password: " password
```

and the following is where I send the information to the remote server. Note, there is an array of servers I must send this to.

```
echo "Adding username and password..."  
ssh root@${dssAssocArray[$key]} "echo username=$username > /etc/smbcredentials"
ssh root@${dssAssocArray[$key]} "echo password=$password >> /etc/smbcredentials"
```

Is there some simple way to dereference the ' (if that's the correct term) or any other special character that might cause an escape?

Comment: Related: [How to execute an arbitrary simple command over ssh without knowing the login shell of the remote user?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205567)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make it:

```
echo "Adding username and password..."  
ssh "root@${dssAssocArray[$key]}" 'cat > /etc/smbcredentials' << EOF
username=$username
password=$password
EOF
```

Comment: Have seen here documents before but haven't really been comfortable using them. Will give it more of a try. Thank you.

Comment: Just applied this. Had some slight issues with the EOF not being found for here document but found an explanation as to why with whitespaces being the issue. Included <<-EOF and tabs to fit the structure of my code. Thank you again.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to get around that by simply quoting your inner strings on the `ssh` command.  For example

```
echo "Adding username and password..."  
ssh root@${dssAssocArray[$key]} "echo \"username=$username\" > /etc/smbcredentials"
ssh root@${dssAssocArray[$key]} "echo \"password=$password\" >> /etc/smbcredentials"
```

Comment: That just moves the problem to the `"`, `$`, backtick, backslash characters. That also assumes the login shell of root understands those `"` as quoting operators (likely).