# pass variable in ssh

Tags: shell-script, ssh, here-document

I'm trying to pass a variable to ssh remote but not works. My code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
conexion="user@xx.yy.zz.pp"
parameter="$1"
ssh -T $conexion <<'ENDSSH' 
clear
echo "$parameter"
ENDSSH
```

I execute:

```
./script.sh try
```

It says me:

```
parameter: Undefined variable.
```

any help please?

Comment: try using ENDSSH without single quote.

Comment: @user650034 if this solved your problem please mark an answer as approved.

Comment: Related: [How to execute an arbitrary simple command over ssh without knowing the login shell of the remote user?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205567)

Answer (score 14):

Passing variables (environment variables) over `ssh` is possible but generally restricted.

You need to tell the client to send them. For instance with OpenSSH, that's with:

```
ssh -o SendEnv=parameter host cmd...
```

But you also need the server to accept it (`AcceptEnv` configuration directive with OpenSSH). Accepting any variable is a big security risk so is generally not done by default, though some ssh deployments allow some variables under some namespace (like `LC_*` in some OpenSSH deployments).

You also need to export the variable before calling `ssh`, like:

```
LC_parameter="$parameter" ssh -o SendEnv=LC_parameter host csh << 'END'
echo $LC_parameter:q
END
```

Above, we're passing the content of the `$parameter` `bash` shell variable as the `LC_parameter` environment variable to `ssh`. `ssh` sends that over to `sshd`, which if it accepts it, passes it as an environment variable to the login shell of the user which then passes it to that `csh` command (which can then expand it).

But as mentioned earlier, that won't work unless the administrator of the `host` machine has added a `AcceptEnv LC_parameter` or `AcceptEnv LC_*` (that one sometimes done by default) to the `sshd` configuration.

The `Undefined variable` error message in your example suggests the login shell of the remote user is `csh` or `tcsh`. It's better to explicitly invoke the  shell to avoid surprises (`ssh host csh` also means a tty is not requested so you don't need `-T`). Note the `$LC_parameter:q` syntax, which is the `csh` way to pass the content of a variable verbatim, not `"$LC_parameter"` which doesn't work if the variable contains newline characters.

If using `LC_*` variables is not an option, then alternatively, you can have the *client* shell (`bash` in your case) expand the variable. A naive way would be with

```
ssh host csh << END
echo "$variable"
END
```

But that would be dangerous as the content of the variable would be interpreted by the remote shell. If `$variable` contains `` `reboot` `` or `"; reboot; : "` for instance, that would have bad consequences.

So, you'd need first to make sure the variable is properly quoted in the syntax of the remote shell. Here, I would avoid `csh` where it's hard to do reliably and use `sh`/`bash`/`ksh` instead.

Use a helper function to do the sh quoting:

```
shquote() {
  awk -v q=\' -v b='\\' '
    BEGIN{
      for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) {
        gsub(q, q b q q, ARGV[i])
       printf "%s ", q ARGV[i] q
      }
      print ""
      exit
    }' "$@"
}
```

And call `ssh` as:

```
ssh host sh << END
parameter=$(shquote "$parameter")
echo "\$parameter"
END
```

See how we escape the third `$` so the expansion of `$parameter` is done by the remote shell, not the local one.

Comment: no need to be environment variables, variables can be expanded, and passed as text. This seems to be the intention, and is what is done in @ddnomad's answer.

Comment: Good explanation and use of `SendEnv` and `AcceptEnv` as using these properly passes _a variable_ rather than _a value_.  This is, strictly speaking, what was asked for.

Comment: @richard, but as I say, that naive approach is unreliable and dangerous. My answer also gives details on how to do that expansion reliably/safely

Comment: @Kusalananda, a systems analyst must not answer what the customer was “strictly speaking”, they have to work out what they want, often with a series of questions. I have been in many situations, where a customer will ask for something, using words in the domain of programmer/software engineer/analyst, with no idea what the words really mean, and them members of my team will take there words at face value and deliver them something that does not swing.

Answer (score 4):

Among other tricks (like passing `LC_*` environment variables) you can do the following:

```
PARAMETER="123"
ssh user@host PARAMETER="$PARAMETER" bash -s <<- 'EOF'
    echo $PARAMETER
EOF
```

The advantage of the approach is absence of the requirement to `export PARAMETER`, adding its name to `AcceptEnv` (in case of names not starting from `LC_`) in config `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on remote host, adding to `SendEnv` on local host (to `-o` or to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`).

Comment: This has the same code injection problem as ddnomad's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Removing quotes from `ENDSSH` on the 4th line should help.

Courtesy: @Archemar in comments to the question.

**WARNING** As it was stated by @StéphaneChazelas in the comment to this answer, this sollution would cause the `$parameter` variable in the here doc to be expanded by the local shell, which means the content of the variable would be interpreted as shell code by the remote shell, which means it introduces a command injection vulnerability. **So generally it's discouraged to do so.**

Comment: That would cause the `$parameter` variable in the here doc to be expanded by the local shell, which means the content of the variable would be interpreted as shell code by the remote shell, which means it introduces a command injection vulnerability for instance if the value of `$parameter` is not entirely under your control and you've not sanitized it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas good point I would add a warning to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf %q`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
conexion="user@xx.yy.zz.pp"
parameter="$1"
ssh -T $conexion parameter="$(printf %q "$parameter");" <<'ENDSSH' 
clear
echo "$parameter"
ENDSSH
```

Just to get this in order: `parameter="$(printf %q "$parameter");" ...` is simply setting a variable before a command as in `x=5; echo $x` but it uses `printf %q` which quotes the `$parameter` safely.

I like this solution because it does not depend on the trick sending environment variables and therefore does not depend on the `AcceptEnv` setting on the ssh server.

Answer (score 0):

Insert single quotes inside double quotes:

```
$ file_name="one two"
$ ssh remote ls "'$file_name'"
ls: cannot access 'one two': No such file or directory
```

The variable gets substituted first, without removing single quotes. This way the content is sent to ssh single-quoted.

Comment: If `file_name` contains a single quote this fails horribly.