# Why does exporting a variable in an ssh shell print the list of exported variables?

Tags: bash, ssh

Consider this:

```
$ ssh localhost bash -c 'export foo=bar'
terdon@localhost's password: 
declare -x DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"
declare -x HOME="/home/terdon"
declare -x LOGNAME="terdon"
declare -x MAIL="/var/spool/mail/terdon"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
declare -x PWD="/home/terdon"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x SHLVL="2"
declare -x SSH_CLIENT="::1 55858 22"
declare -x SSH_CONNECTION="::1 55858 ::1 22"
declare -x USER="terdon"
declare -x XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_ID="c5"
declare -x _="/usr/bin/bash"
```

Why does exporting a variable within a `bash -c` session run via ssh result in that list of `declare -x` commands (the list of currently exported variables, as far as I can tell)?

Running the same thing without the `bash -c` doesn't do that:

```
$ ssh localhost  'export foo=bar'
terdon@localhost's password: 
$
```

Nor does it happen if we don't `export`:

```
$ ssh localhost bash -c 'foo=bar'
terdon@localhost's password: 
$
```

I tested this by sshing from one Ubuntu machine to another (both running bash 4.3.11) and on an Arch machine, sshing to itself as shown above (bash version 4.4.5).

What's going on here? Why does exporting a variable inside a `bash -c` call produce this output?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but the output is the result of running `export`. Zsh does the same thing.

Comment: @StephenKitt yes, I know it's `export`, I'm trying to understand what's happening. I'll edit to clarify that this only happens when exporting.

Comment: Ah OK, I'd read "the list of currently exported variables, as far as I can tell" as meaning that you didn't know where the output was coming from.

Comment: @StephenKitt I mean I'm not sure if that's *every* exported variable or a specific subset or what. Oh! You mean it's the output of `export` run alone? That I hadn't understood.

Comment: Note that `foo=bar` doesn't appear in the list.

Comment: @deltab no, of course not, because that was never exported. That's precisely the issue as I learned.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you run a command through `ssh`, it is run by calling your `$SHELL` with the `-c` flag:

```
-c    If the -c option is present, then commands are read from 
      the first non-option argument command_string.  If there  are
      arguments  after the command_string, the first argument is 
      assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to
      the positional parameters.
```

So, `ssh remote_host "bash -c foo"` will actually run:

```
/bin/your_shell -c 'bash -c foo'
```

Now, because the command you are running (`export foo=bar`) contains spaces and is not properly quoted to form a whole, the `export` is taken as the command to be run and the rest are saved in the positional parameters array. This means that `export` is run and `foo=bar` is passed to it as `$0`. The final result is the same as running

```
/bin/your_shell -c 'bash -c export'
```

The correct command would be:

```
ssh remote_host "bash -c 'export foo=bar'"
```

Answer (score 9):

`ssh` concatenates the arguments with spaces and has the login shell of the remote user interpret it, so in:

```
ssh localhost bash -c 'export foo=bar'
```

`ssh` is asking the remote shell to interpret the

```
bash -c export foo=bar
```

command (in effect, if the remote host is Unix-like, it will run the remote shell with `the-shell`, `-c` and `bash -c export foo=bar` as arguments).

Most shells will interpret that command line as running the `bash` command with `bash`, `-c`, `export` and `foo=bar` as arguments (so run `export` while `$0` contains `foo=bar`) while you'd want it to run it with `bash`, `-c` and `export foo=bar` as arguments.

For that, you'd need to use a command line like:

```
ssh localhost "bash -c 'export foo=bar'"
```

(or:

```
ssh localhost bash -c \'export foo=bar\'
```

for that matters) so the:

```
bash -c 'export foo=bar'
```

command line be passed to the remote shell. That command line would be interpreted by most shells as running the `bash` command with `bash`, `-c` and `export foo=bar` as arguments. Note that using

```
ssh localhost 'bash -c "export foo=bar"'
```

would not work if the login shell of the remote user was `rc` or `es` for instance where `"` is not a special quoting operator. Single quotes are the most portable quoting operators (though there is some variation on how they are interpreted between shells, see [How to execute an arbitrary simple command over ssh without knowing the login shell of the remote user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205567) for more on that).