# Problem with passing path containing spaces and brackets

Tags: bash, ssh, filenames, path, arguments

I use Thunar file explorer and pass pathname and filename to a script audioplay.  audioplay runs play command on my android via ssh which plays a song.

audioplay script :: `cat audioplay`

```
if [ $# -eq 1 ] ; then
echo "   Playing..." "$@"
sshpass -p $passwd  ssh root@192.168.43.10 -p $port  play "$@"
else
 echo "  No Input audio file."
fi
```

play script on my android :: `cat play`

```
    #!/data/bin/bash
    # Avoid linker errors due to libOpenSLES.so:
    echo "File ::" "$@"
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH= exec /data/bin/blob/play-audio "$@"
```

Problem is Path does not get passed correctly to play command over ssh. Path with multi spaces becomes single space  and brackets create syntax error.

Example :

For file  `18. Warriors.flac` present in `/sdcard/Music/Imagine Dragons - Smoke   Mirrors -Deluxe Edition-2015`

Path sent to audioplay is correct :: `/sdcard/Music/Imagine Dragons - Smoke   Mirrors -Deluxe Edition-2015/18. Warriors.flac`

But the path received by play script is  wrong :: `/sdcard/Music/Imagine Dragons - Smoke Mirrors -Deluxe Edition-2015/18. Warriors.flac`
Multi spaces are turned into single space. Why ?

Then the main `play-audio` binary gets only path `/sdcard/Music/Imagine` upto first space only.

Example 2 ::

I tried with file having brackets  :: `44. Go Tell Aunt Rhody -Resident Evil- (Short Version).flac`
Path received by audioplay script is correct :: `/sdcard/Music/44. Go Tell Aunt Rhody -Resident Evil- (Short Version).flac`
But I get this error :: `sh: syntax error: '(' unexpected`

I tried with passing `$@`  `$*` `"$@"` and `"$*"`. But none of them worked for me.

Comment: See [How to execute an arbitrary simple command over ssh without knowing the login shell of the remote user?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/205567). Also remember to quote your variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote it again:

```
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] ; then
    echo "   Playing..." "$1"
    sshpass -p "$passwd" ssh root@192.168.43.10 -p "$port" "play '$1'"
else
    echo "  No Input audio file."
fi
```

The thing is that the first layer of quotes, the `"$@"` are expanded when you run the `sshpass` command. So by the time you log in, launch the remote shell and execute `play`, you have an unquoted string, so your script chokes on whitespace. By enclosing it in a second layer of quotes, you ensure that it is passed quoted to the remote command.

This should work assuming that i) the remote machine is running `sh` or `bash` or a similar shell and ii) your file names don't contain single quotes. To make it truly robust, please see [How to execute an arbitrary simple command over ssh without knowing the login shell of the remote user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205567).

For properly quoting an arbitrary string (or even a list of arbitrary strings so you can pass more than one argument to `play`) in the `sh` syntax, we can use that `shquote()` function mentioned there:

```
shquote() {
  LC_ALL=C awk -v q=\' -v b='\\' '
    BEGIN{
      for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) {
        gsub(q, q b q q, ARGV[i])
        printf "%s ", q ARGV[i] q
      }
      print ""
      exit
    }' "$@"
}
if [ "$#" -ge 1 ] ; then
    echo "   Playing..." "$@"
    sshpass -p "$passwd" ssh root@192.168.43.10 -p "$port" "play $(shquote "$@")"
else
    echo "  No Input audio file."
fi
```

It would quote `Sgt. Pepper's lonely hearts club band.flac` as `'Sgt. Pepper'\''s lonely hearts club band.mp3'` which is correct for `sh` (and `evil';reboot;: '.flac` as `'evil'\'';reboot;: '\''.flac'` instead of rebooting the remote machine (do you *have* to run that `play` command as `root`?)).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas since it's an Android device, it's safe (I think) to assume the remote is running `sh`. But yes, it will indeed break on single quotes.

Comment: It worked.  Thanks a lot.   I spent hours on it searching and trying.

Comment: @jonny789 you're welcome. But do read Stéphane's answer in the linked post for more detail.

Comment: Yes.  I login to android as root user. Running play as root works without any issue.