# How to pass the second argument in the bash function

Tags: bash, shell-script

Let's say that I have this `bash function` where I firstly connect to a Remote Desktop and then I want to use a second argument while I am connected to the command line of the Remote Desktop (that's why I've used the single quotation marks. However, I am not sure how to surround the `$2` argument.

```
my_func () {
ssh blah blah blah $1 'cd $2'
}
```

I am not sure about the way I should specify the second argument. I've tried to run this function in the local machine as:
`my_func a b`, where b is a directory in the Remote Desktop, but I don't seem to have the expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to quote `$2` in a way suitable for the login shell of the remote user. For instance, assuming it's Bourne-like:

```
shquote() {
  LC_ALL=C awk -v q=\' '
    BEGIN{
      for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) {
        gsub(q, q "\\" q q, ARGV[i])
        printf "%s ", q ARGV[i] q
      }
      print ""
    }' "$@"
}

my_func () {
  ssh blah blah blah "$1" "cd -- $(shquote "$2")"
}
```

For instance, `shquote()` would transform `Stephane's dir` into `'Stephane'\''s dir'` so the `cd -- 'Stephane'\''s dir'` command line is interpreted by the remote Bourne-like shell as running `cd` with a `Stephane's dir` directory argument.

In any case running a shell on a remote host that just does `cd` is not going to achieve anything useful.

More reading (and more options, including for the cases where the login shell of the remote user is not Bourne-like) at [How to execute an arbitrary simple command over ssh without knowing the login shell of the remote user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205567)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll definitely check it (`cd` is just an example for simplicity, it's not the actual purpose)!

Comment: While my solution might work in the "standard" case, this solution is much more robust. My solution will for example fail if `$2` contains `'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_func () {
ssh blah blah blah $1 'cd $2'
}
```

Do not use single quotes. Bash variables are not expanded when you use single quotes, try `ssh blah blah blah $1 "cd $2"` it should work. Make sure that changing single quotes to double quotes does not make bash expand other things in your command though, or you might get an unexpected result.

Comment: You're welcome, [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) is some documentation on shell variable expansion for further reading if you are interested.

Comment: That won't work properly if `$2` contains any character special to the remote shell (like space, `;`, `$`, `&`...).

Comment: Indeed it is not safe if used naively, but you could also escape the special characters directly in the input arguments right ? It depends on who will be on the user end eventually.

Answer (score 1):

what about:

```
my_func() {
    blah blah blah blah $1 "cd \"$2\""
}
```

this doesn't work for parameters containing `"`.