# sh recursive copy (cp -r) - How to exclude subfolder

Tags: shell, ssh, cp

I need to run a remote script using `ssh` via `Ruby` ([net/ssh](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh)) to recursively copy a folder and exclude a subfolder. I am looking for the fastest way to do it so `rsync` is not good. Also, I understand that `ssh` uses `sh` and not `bash`.

In bash I do:

```
cp -r srcdir/!(subdir) dstdir
```

and it works fine. However when I launch the script via `ssh` I receive the error

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

because it is using `sh`.

I have checked the `sh` man page, but there is no option to exclude files.

Is it my assumption of `ssh` using `sh` correct?
Any alternative suggestion?

**EDIT 1:**
In case it is useful, the output of `sudo cat /etc/shells` is the following:

```
# /etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/sh
/bin/dash
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
/usr/bin/tmux
/usr/bin/screen
```

**EDIT 2:**
OK. So bash it is available and that does not seems to be the problem. I have verified that the ssh is actually using `bash`. The issue seems to be related to the escaping of parenthesis or exclamation mark.
I have tried to run the command from the shell (macos) and this is the actual command:

```
ssh -i .ssh/key.pem ubuntu@X.X.X.X 'mkdir /home/ubuntu/OpenFOAM/ubuntu-4.1/run/LES_New-Area_residuals2/N; cp -r /home/ubuntu/OpenFOAM/ubuntu-4.1/run/LES_New-Area_residuals2/mesh/!\(constant\) /home/ubuntu/OpenFOAM/ubuntu-4.1/run/LES_New-Area_residuals2/N; ln -s /home/ubuntu/OpenFOAM/ubuntu-4.1/run/LES_New-Area_residuals2/mesh/constant /home/ubuntu/OpenFOAM/ubuntu-4.1/run/LES_New-Area_residuals2/N/constant'
```

In this way I receive a different error

```
cp: cannot stat '/home/ubuntu/OpenFOAM/ubuntu-4.1/run/LES_New-Area_residuals2/mesh/!(constant)': No such file or directory
```

**EDIT 3:**
Based on the comments I have changed my command adding `extglob`

If I use

```
ssh -i .ssh/key.pem ubuntu@X.X.X.X 'shopt -s extglob; mkdir /home/ubuntu/OpenFOAM/ubuntu-4.1/run/LES_New-Area_residuals2/N; cp -r /home/ubuntu/OpenFOAM/ubuntu-4.1/run/LES_New-Area_residuals2/mesh/!\(constant\) /home/ubuntu/OpenFOAM/ubuntu-4.1/run/LES_New-Area_residuals2/N; ln -s /home/ubuntu/OpenFOAM/ubuntu-4.1/run/LES_New-Area_residuals2/mesh/constant /home/ubuntu/OpenFOAM/ubuntu-4.1/run/LES_New-Area_residuals2/N/constant'
```

I receive the following error:

```
cp: cannot stat '/home/ubuntu/OpenFOAM/ubuntu-4.1/run/LES_New-Area_residuals2/mesh/!(constant)': No such file or directory
```

If I do not escape the parenthesis I get

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: `ssh` (well `sshd`) uses the login shell of the remote user. Could be anything.

Comment: Unix doesn't have folders, only directories. :)

Comment: In situations like this I often like to just develop the script on the remote host, then either 1) leave it there, ssh in (programmatically if need be) and execute it or 2) if it changes every time, scp it over, execute it via ssh, and then delete it. An extra step maybe, but you don't end up with escaping nightmares and globs expanding locally instead of remotely and all that. Otherwise I would always use heredoc format like @StéphaneChazelas uses below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SSH runs your login shell on the remote system, whatever that is. But `!(foo)` requires `shopt -s extglob`, which you might not have set on the remote.

Try this to see if SSH runs Bash on the remote side:

```
ssh me@somehost 'echo "$BASH_VERSION"'
```

If that prints anything, but your startup scripts don't set `extglob`, you can do it by hand on the command passed to `ssh`:

```
ssh me@somehost 'shopt -s extglob
    echo srcdir/!(subdir)'                                 
 # or
ssh me@somehost $'shopt -s extglob\n echo srcdir/!(subdir)'
```

`extglob` affects the parsing of the command line, and only takes effect after a newline, so we have to put a literal newline there, a semicolon isn't enough.

```
ssh me@somehost 'shopt -s extglob; echo srcdir/!(subdir)'
```

---

Also not that if you escape the parenthesis with backslashes, they lose their special properties, like any other glob characters. This is not what you want to do in this case.

```
$ touch foo bar; shopt -s extglob; set +o histexpand
$ echo *
bar foo
$ echo !(foo)
bar
$ echo \*
*
$ echo !\(foo\)
!(foo)
```

Answer (score 10):

I don't know why you think that rsync would be slow. The speed of a copy is mostly determined by the speed of the disk. Rsync has many options to specify what you want included and excluded, so it gives you much better control than shell globbing.

As the bash manual states, the `!(patter)` is only recognized in bash if `extglob` is set. In your example you didn't set `extglob`. Further, a `bash` started as `sh` is still `bash`, but will disable some extensions for compatibility.

The SSH server will start the user's login shell, as specified in `/etc/passwd`. You can either change the shell, or use that shell to start another shell that fits your needs better.

Comment: I tested with `time`. `time cp -r mesh/!(constant) N` -> real 1.04s and `time rsync -a mesh/ N --exclude=constant` -> real 1.8s

Comment: @Rojj that’s apples to oranges comparison.  For one thing, you’re using -a for rsync but not for cp.  That involves preservation of permissions and other attributes, so you’re not actually doing the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

A few notes first:

- the ssh server doesn't start `sh` to interpret the command line sent by the client, it runs the login shell of the user on the remote host, as `that-shell -c <the-string-provided-by-the-client>`. The login shell of the remote user could be anything. Bear in mind that some shells like `tcsh`, `fish` or `rc` have very different syntax from that of `sh`.
- it is really a command line, or more exactly a string (that can contain newline characters, so several lines). Even if you do `ssh host cmd arg1 'arg 2'` where `cmd`, `arg1` and `arg 2` are three arguments passed to `ssh`, `ssh` concatenates those arguments with spaces and actually sends the `cmd arg1 arg 2` string  to `sshd`, and the remote shell would split that into `cmd`, `arg1`, `arg` and `2`.
- `!(subdir)` is a glob operator (a `ksh` glob operator also supported by `zsh -o kshglob` and `bash -O extglob`). Like all globs, it excludes hidden files, so beware there may be other files that it excludes.

Here, to avoid the problem with finding out the right syntax for the remote shell, you can actually tell that other shell to start the shell you want and feed it the code via stdin (one of the options listed at [How to execute an arbitrary simple command over ssh without knowing the login shell of the remote user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205567))

```
ssh host 'bash -O extglob -O dotglob' << 'EOF'
cp -r srcdir/!(subdir) dstdir/
EOF
```

`bash -O extglob -O dotglob` is a command line that is understood the same by all major shells, including Bourne-like ones, csh, rc, fish... The above would work as long as `bash` is installed and is in the user's `$PATH` (default `$PATH`, possibly modified by the user's login shell like with `~/.zshenv` for `zsh`, `~/.cshrc` for `csh`, `~/.bashrc` for `bash`).

POSIXly (though in practice, you may find that more systems have a `bash` command than a `pax` command), you could do:

```
ssh host sh << 'EOF'
cd srcdir && pax -rw -'s|^\.//\./subdir\(/.*\)\{0,1\}$||' .//. /path/to/destdir/
EOF
```

`-s` applies substitutions to the paths being transferred. When that substitution expands to nothing, the file is excluded. The problem is that substitutions also apply  to target of symlinks. That's why we use `.//.` above to make it less likely that a symlink be affected.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think `ssh` is limited  to using `sh`. It rather depends on what is installed on the target system, how the user is set up, and what shells are allowed in  `/etc/shells`.

Did you consider the `chsh` command?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it in a fast way, you can look at `rsync` with a different encryption algorithm. This gives you the option to easily exclude etc., at not much speed sacrifice.

`rsync -aHAXxv --numeric-ids --progress -e "ssh -T -c arcfour -o Compression=no -x" user@<source>:<source_dir> <dest_dir>`

together with adding the `arcfour` encryption to the line starting with `Ciphers` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, if not already enabled, gives you an acceptable speed.

WARNING: The `arcfour` encryption is **insecure**. Do NOT run this over insecure channels. If you are concerned about access to the server from insecure channels using `arcfour` encryption, change the `etc/ssh/ssh_config` with a *host-specific* part for your source host - Create a `Host` section in your ssh_config for your source host, you can use `Ciphers arcfour` there to mirror the above `-c` switch, which restricts `arcfour` encryption to this host only.

For details, refer to `ssh_config` man pages.

However, if your CPUs support the AES-NI instruction set, try switching to aes128-gcm@openssh.com (yes, that's the cipher name, including the @ stuff), which will use the blazingly fast (with AES-NI) AES128-GCM.

So, with a CPU supporting AES-NI, change `"ssh -T -c arcfour -o Compression=no -x"` to `"ssh -T -c aes128-gcm@openssh.com -o Compression=no -x"` for more secure results.

### Explanation

#### rsync

- (Don't use `-z`, it is much slower)
- `a`: archive mode - rescursive, preserves owner, preserves permissions, preserves modification times, preserves group, copies symlinks as symlinks, preserves device files.
- `H`: preserves hard-links
- `A`: preserves ACLs
- `X`: preserves extended attributes
- `x`: don't cross file-system boundaries
- `v`: increase verbosity
- `--numeric-ds`: don't map uid/gid values by user/group name
- if you need to sync, add `--delete`: delete extraneous files from dest dirs (differential clean-up during sync)
- `--progress`: show progress during transfer

#### ssh

- `T`: turn off pseudo-tty to decrease cpu load on destination.
- `c arcfour`: use the weakest but fastest SSH encryption. Must specify "Ciphers arcfour" in sshd_config on destination.
- `o Compression=no`: Turn off SSH compression.
- `x`: turn off X forwarding if it is on by default.

The beef is in the `ssh` options - if you just use `rsync -av` and the `-e ssh -T -c arcfour -o Compression=no -x"` part, you can get these speeds as well.

---

## Comparison:

- 13.6 MB/s  `rsync -az`
- 16.7 MB/s  `scp -Cr`
- 44.8 MB/s  `rsync -a`
- 59.8 MB/s  `sftp`
- 61.2 MB/s  `scp -r`
- 61.4 MB/s  `sftp  -R 128 -B 65536`
- 62.4 MB/s  `rsync -a -P -e "ssh -T -c arcfour -o Compression=no -x"`
- 143.5 MB/s  `scp -r -c arcfour`
- 144.2 MB/s  `sftp -oCiphers=arcfour`

*Sources*:

https://gist.github.com/KartikTalwar/4393116

http://nz2nz.blogspot.com/2018/05/rsync-scp-sftp-speed-test.html

Comment: Well, they seem to be running `cp -r` within the remote system, so the encryption used by the SSH connection isn't really relevant. In any case `arcfour` is considered [rather broken](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7465) and OpenSSH [disables it along with others on the server by default since version 6.7 (2014-10-06)](https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html). In any case, `ssh -o Ciphers='aes128-ctr'` gives me about 90 MB/s, which should be fast enough on a 1 Gbit/s link.

Comment: Yes, arcfour is broken, but it's not supposed to be SECURE shell for this case, but more 'comfortable shell' with no emphasis on the encryption. I wouldn't use this over insecure connections, that's correct. If 'aes128-ctr' is fast enough, it can and should be used instead.

Comment: See also my extended answer for usage with CPUs which support AES-NI.

Answer (score 2):

As per my calculations, the fastest full copy is always using 'tar' (here assuming GNU `tar` or compatible).

```
mkdir -p photos2 &&
  tar -C photos -cf - --exclude=./.thumbcache . |
  tar -C photos2 -xpf -
```

And `tar` has ton of options to manipulate attributes, permissions and file selection/exclusion. For example, the above command excludes the top level subfolder called .thumbcache while copying.

Comment: Note that `--exclude=.thumbcache` excludes *all* the `.thumbcache` files, not only the one at the top-level. With GNU `tar` (not `bsdtar`), you can use `--exclude=./.thumbcache` to only exclude the top-level `.thumbcache` file.