# How to run SSH commands in a function and store output in a variable?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to find (and store to a variable) the path of a file that is stored on another server by running the following command in one of my functions (included in .bashrc):

`FILE_PATH=$(ssh -T user@host 'find <directory> -name *<filename>*')`

However this is not returning any output. I have checked that there should be a file in the location that is grabbed, and I have also been able to replicate the command and store output to variable on the command line, but it does not work when running the function.

Does anyone know what's going on and why the command isn't working?

EDIT:

Here is a representation of what I am seeing:

```
function get_path {
    FILE=$1
    FILE_PATH=$(ssh -T user@hostB 'find /home/daverbuj -name *${FILE}*')
    echo "Here is the file: ${FILE_PATH}"
}
```

```
[daverbuj@hostA]$ FILE_A=$(ssh -T user@hostB 'find /home/daverbuj -name foo.bar')
[daverbuj@hostA]$ echo $FILE_A
/home/daverbuj/foo.bar

[daverbuj@hostA]$ get_path foo.bar
Here is the file:
```

I am seeing what I expect when I run from the command line, but not when I run the function.

Comment: Edited. Both servers are RedHat v7.7. The function is in my .bashrc which is sourced every time I edit it. I am suspecting maybe having it in .bashrc is an issue and will try to make it as a standalone script.

Comment: The issue with .bashrc would be that the file isn't sourced when you ssh, or in various other cases, so that would just make the function error with a `command not found`. I doubt it would make a difference otherwise. Can you show the _exact_ function? I doubt you're looking for a file named `foo.bar`, right? Is the `find` command a bit more complex in reality? There may also be quoting issues that will affect if you are passing the variable or the variable's contents, so if you can show the exact thing that would help at least rule some issues out.

Comment: The full command is: `ssh -T daverbuj@host 'find /xxxxx/prod_archive/research/xxxx/xxxx/xxxxx -maxdepth 3 -nowarn -name *xxxxx*region-2_cov_report.bed' 2>/dev/null`

Again, the weird part is that when I run this by itself I get output as expected. Running this from the function in bashrc returns nothing.

Comment: OK, please add that to your question but make sure you get the quoting _exactly_ as you have it. Specifically, whether the name of the bed file is quoted or not since that could explain what's happening (if you don't quote it, the `*` will be expanded before the `find` command is run so it will work if you have a file matching the glob in your current directory). Also try without the `2>/dev/null` in case you get any useful error.

Comment: Yup that was it! I changed the single quotes to double quotes in that find command. Thanks so much for your help! Adding that part to my original question.

Comment: what ever happens in that ssh, the `get_path foo.bar` should print `Here is the file: foo.bar` since it's printing what it got in `$1`... I'm a bit surprised it'd return no output, since you probably don't have `$FILE` set on the remote, so the remote should expand `*${FILE}*` to all filenames in the directory, and `find` should complain about extra args since it gets `find -name abc def ghi ...` Are you sure you don't get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
get_path() {
  local name=$1
  readarray -td '' reply < <(
    LC_FILE_NAME=$name ssh -o SendEnv=LC_FILE_NAME -n -T user@hostB '
      LC_ALL=C find /home/daverbuj -name "*$LC_FILE_NAME*" -print0')
  (( ${#reply[@]} )) &&
    echo "File path${reply[2]+s} with that name:" &&
    printf ' - %s\n' "${reply[@]}"
}
```

- no need to use the ksh style of function definition (`function f {...}`), `bash` supports the standard `f() compound-command` as well.
- there could be more than one matching file. To separate them out reliably, you need to use NUL as delimiter (`-print0`). `bash` variables can't hold NULs, but since version 4.4, its `readarray` builtin can split a NUL delimited input stream into elements of an array with `-d ''`.
- `*` is a glob operator, so it needs to be quoted for both the local shell and remote shell so it be passed literally to `find` for it's `-name` name pattern matching operator.
- You don't want to have the local shell expand a variable into the code passed to the remote shell as that would constitute some form of arbitrary command injection vulnerability, instead here, we've passing the `$name` value to the remote shell via a `LC_FILE_NAME` environment variable (assumes `sshd` on the remote host is configured with `AcceptEnv LC_*` which is common). In your code, you had the remote shell expand a `$FILE` variable (though had forgotten to quote it as well as the `*`), but you hadn't passed that variable from the local shell to the remote shell.
- `$REPLY` for scalar and `$reply` for array is a common convention for a variable name where we return a result to the caller.
- You can't use `echo` for arbitrary data (for data that you can't guarantee won't contain backslashes or start with `-`).
- `-name '*foo*'` could fail to match all files with `foo` in their name in locales using multi-byte charsets such as UTF-8, as failure to decoding the file names into that charset would trip the `fnmatch()` used by `find`'s `-name`. Hence the `LC_ALL=C` to fix to a single-byte locale.
- here, we're returning a failure exit status unless at least one file was found and it was printed properly.
- We're using the `-n` option of `ssh` to avoid it consuming input from stdin. You may also want to add a `-o BatchMode=yes` for more tuning relevant to processing meant to be unattended.

More reading on those here:

- [How to execute an arbitrary simple command over ssh without knowing the login shell of the remote user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205567)
- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/22565)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Answer (score 0):

You can reroute `stderr` to `stdout` using

```
OUT=$(ssh -tt -vv user@host.com "remote command" 2>&1 )
```

you can edit something like this in your function and it should work!

Comment: Using `-t` is the last thing you want to do in scripts other than starting an interactive command. See for instance [Why is this binary file transferred over "ssh -t" being changed?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/151916)

Comment: By using `-vv` and `2>&1`, you're storing the errors as well as `ssh`'s debug output into `$OUT` in addition the remote command's output.