# How to display text for non-interactive login shell

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, scripting, login

*What I need*:

I am trying to change /etc/bashrc in such a way that shell could display specific text when the following ssh command is entered

```
ssh user@ip "whoami"
```

But I don't understand what exactly I should change there as I don't understand which line in this files refers to actions when the shell is non-interactive login shell.

*What I tried*:

Without any changes in /etc/bashrc shell returns the user name after that command, so I thought that I needed to change the value of $PS1. I tried to change it, but it did not work.

I also googled that for non-interactive non-login shells BASH_ENV is important, but in my case the shell is non-interactive **login** shell. So should I use $BASH_EVN as well? Should I add it to /etc/bashrc?

Comment: Can you add what the expected output is supposed to look like?

Comment: The result should be like this:

```
ssh user@ip "whoami"
[here shell asks for password: ...]
HELLO [this is the result text that should be displayed]
```

Comment: `ssh user@ip "whoami"` will run `whoami` in a non-interactive [non-login](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/744263/108618) shell on the server.

Answer (score 1):

`~/.bashrc` and the equivalent system-wide one if any (generally `/etc/bash.bashrc`) is normally not read by non-interactive invocations of `bash`. It is also not read by interactive *login* shell invocations, though that's generally considered a misfeature, so you often find the *bash_profile* files work around it by sourcing *bashrc* when interactive.

In `ssh user@host 'some shell code'`, (and if `bash` happens to be the login shell of `user` on `host`), `sshd` on `host` runs `bash -c 'some shell code'`, it's neither an interactive nor a login shell invocation.

Now the bashrc files may be sourced when `bash` is invoked by `sshd` when the `bash` interpreter on the system has been built with [`/* #define SSH_SOURCE_BASHRC */` uncommented in the `config-top.h`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/config-top.h?h=bash-5.2#n109) file in the source which some OSes ([such as Debian](https://sources.debian.org/src/bash/5.2.15-2/config-top.h/#L109)) do.

If you're on such as system, then you should be able to tell if `bash` was invoked from `ssh host 'some bash code'` in the bashrc by checking that:

- it's a non-interactive invocation of `bash`: `[[ $- != *i* ]]`
- it's invoked as `bash -c <some-code>`: `[[ $- = *c* ]]`. When run with `-c`, bash is normally not interactive, so the previous check may be seen as redundant. Exception would be if `bash` is run as `bash -ic 'some code'`.
- it's invoked over `ssh`: `[[ -v SSH_CLIENT || -v SSH2_CLIENT ]]` using the same heuristic as bash does.
- `$SHLVL` is 1 (to avoid cases where `bash` is run again within a ssh session, though in those cases, `bashrc` should not be run when non-interactive, so it would only cover cases where `bashrc` is sourced explicitly): `[[ $SHLVL = 1 ]]`¹. That's still not necessarily foolproof.

So, at the top of the *bashrc*:

```
if [[ $- != *i* && $- = *c* && (-v SSH_CLIENT || -v SSH2_CLIENT) && $SHLVL = 1 ]]; then
  printf>&2 'I was most likely invoked as ssh host %q\n' "$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING"
  if [[ $BASH_EXECUTION_STRING = whoami ]]; then
    echo Something specific here
  fi
fi
```

<sup>¹ note that we do `$SHLVL = 1` (string comparison) rather than `$SHLVL -eq 1` (number comparison) as [doing the latter would introduce a command injection vulnerability](/q/172103). That should be equivalent as we don't expect `$SHLVL` to contain any other representation of the number 1 such as 01, 0x1...</sup>

Comment: Wow. I always wondered about how `.bashrc` fit into the grand scheme of things. Never knew it isn't called in interactive invokations but duh, maybe that's why I've always seen it being invoked in the `.bash_profile`

Comment: It **is** called in interactive invocations and that's where it should be called, but bash has that quirk that is not called in ones that are *login* ones in addition to being interactive. Other shells don't have the problem. `.profile` is meant to customise your login session, `.shellrc` to customise the shell (for interactive use)

Comment: Stéphane Chazelas, thank you, it worked. I also found shorter alternative: adding condition if [ -z "$PS1" ] then echo "Hello" else ... turned out to be enough to solve my problem.