# Prevent command from running in zsh

Tags: bash, zsh

In bash I can do:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
validate() {
    if [[ "$BASH_COMMAND" == whoami ]]; then
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi
}
set -T
trap 'validate' DEBUG
shopt -s extdebug
```

so that if I run `whoami` nothing happens.

How can I achieve the same in zsh ? I've looked at `preexec` but I couldn't find much information in the [documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html)

Comment: Would it not be easier (in `bash` too) to use `whoami () { false; }`?

Comment: @Kusalananda, actually in zsh (and most Bourne-like shells, bash being an exception), `whoami() false` would be enough. In Korn-like shells including bash and zsh, you can also do `whoami() ((0))`

Comment: Related [How to display text for non-interactive login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/769610). What is with people wanting to hijack whoami these days?

Comment: (even `whoami()(())` or in zsh: `whoami(){!}`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `whoami` was only for illustration purposes. it was the first command I could think of

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use the [`DEBUG` trap](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-trapping-signals-1#:%7E:text=If%20sig%20is%20DEBUG,after%20the%20trap%20is%20executed.) to skip a command in zsh, but the mechanism to indicate skipping is different: you need to [set the `err_exit` option](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-exit-status_002c-trapping#:%7E:text=inside%20DEBUG%20traps,is%20skipped).

```
function validate {
    if [[ "$ZSH_DEBUG_CMD" == whoami ]]; then
        setopt err_exit
    fi
}
trap 'validate' DEBUG
```

Comment: Note that one can always work around it by running `\whoami` or `"whoami"` or `command whoami` or `env whoami` or `sh -c whoami` or `/usr/bin/whoami`...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Or `$(base64 -d <<<d2hvYW1pCg==)`. A blacklist can't be a security measure, and even a whitelist is hard.